# Using a different comment style for commented out code in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm, comments

When commenting out text with PyCharm (by selecting text and hitting a keyboard shortcut), it uses normal `#` comments like this:

[image]

I don't like how similar this looks to actual comments (i.e. me explaining what my code does), so it would like to use a different style of comments (`##`) for commenting out code:

```
def execute_evil_master_plan():
    ## # Start by hijacking a government satellite.
    ## # Doesn't matter which as long as it has a death laser.
    ## satellite = hijack_government_satellite()
    ## 
    ## # aim it towards the white house and fire the laser
    ## coords = google_maps.get_coordinates(WHITE_HOUSE)
    ## satellite.aim(target=coords)
    ## satellite.fire()
```

Is there any way to customize the comment style like this in PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

Use """ before and after your multi-line comment.

```
def execute_evil_master_plan():
    """
    # Start by hijacking a government satellite.
    # Doesn't matter which as long as it has a death laser.
    satellite = hijack_government_satellite()

    # aim it towards the white house and fire the laser
    coords = google_maps.get_coordinates(WHITE_HOUSE)
    satellite.aim(target=coords)
    satellite.fire()
    """
```

Comment: I'm not a fan of this solution for multiple reasons: 1) That's now the function's docstring. 2) It looks like a string, not a comment. 3) I have to type those quotation marks manually; I can't just hit a keyboard shortcut and let PyCharm comment out the code for me.